# How do I retrieve AzureAD attributes after signIn with Asp.Net and OpenIDAuthentication and SAML2?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I am signing into AzureAd using the following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

I get back a id_token and code and am redirected to my reply url.

Here is my startup:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                ClientId = clId,
                Authority = authUrl,
                RedirectUri = redirectUrl,
                // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = logoutUrl,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
                // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false // This is a simplification
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

How can I retrieve attributes such as the email address when redirected to my replyUrl?

Answer (score 0):

Application developers can use optional claims in their Azure AD apps to specify which claims they want in tokens sent to their application.

The email claim is included in a token only if an email address is associated with the user account, which is not always the case. If it uses the email scope, your app should be prepared to handle a case in which the email claim does not exist in the token.

If you have to get the email then you have to enable optional claim , Please check the doc below for further explanation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims

Also please make sure to add the Scope in you request to get the email. Please add the permission to Sign in and read user profile under Delegated Permissions of your Azure AD application.

Additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes

https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-ad-custom-attributes-and-optional-claims-from-an-asp-dot-net-application/

Hope it helps.

Comment: My sso is set to use SAMl2. Can I send a openId request despite this?